# Keycloak Email verification

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I have a keycloak client called NAME which is the client for my backend auths and my admin user is known as ADMIN.

I tried to configure smtp for email verification on that realm for the client and I tried to test it.

Right after keying in the credentials to my smtp server, keycloak logged me out out of the admin user and the test that comes is as displayed: [image: here]
I need a workaround to restore my user to how it to enable me log in to the admin console